# Combine contours vertically and get convex hull - opencv - python

Tags: python, opencv, contour, convex-hull

I have character images like this:

[image]

After getting `contours` and `convexHull` the output is like this:

[image]

For that I used following code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('input.png', -1)

ret, threshed_img = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),
                        127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(threshed_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contours:
    # get convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [hull], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)    
cv2.imwrite("output.png", img)
```

As you can see in the **following image** there are identified contours which are vertically aligned with the original character. But those are separated with the original core character. (Those are actually modifiers of the language called sinhala - සිංහල)

[image]

Now I want to merge those vertically aligned contours with the core character. Ultimately the output should be as follows. How could I do that efficiently?

[image]

Comment: You could try merging based on distance between two contours' centers

Comment: I thought about that, what if then I end up with merging horizontally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try performing a morphological operation using a kernel with a vertical rectangular shape. In this way ceratin characters above the original characters would be joined as one.

```
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 30))
threshed = cv2.morphologyEx(th2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rect_kernel)
cv2.imshow('threshed', threshed)
```

[image]

```
imgContours, Contours, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in Contours:
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    cv2.drawContours(img2, [hull], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1) 
cv2.imshow('convex hull', img2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JeruLuke this is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can try merging contours based on distance between the contours' centers. Since you want to put more emphasis on the vertical connections, you can modify your distance function so that it puts more importance on vertical connections. This can be done by treating horizontal distances as more "expensive" in terms of threshold. For example, to put emphasis on vertical proximity more than horizontal proximity, you can scale the horizonal difference with a larger than 1 constant:

```
distance = hypotenuse(distance_x * 5, distance_y)
```

Comment: Suppose I could find two contours to be merged using this logic. Then How could I merge them?

Comment: As described here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/opencv-c-connect-nearby-contours-based-on-distance-between-them

Comment: You put the 2 contours' points in 1 set and convex hull on that

Comment: The link you provided is not efficient. In the answer it self mentioned that. Anyway thank you for your answer.